# Handle optgroup in select box with angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

How can I get the optgroup label value in onchange function on a select box in angular 4

I have following select box in a form with multiple dates as options group and time in 24 hour format for booking like 1000,1200 and 1400 for 10AM,12PM and 2PM respectively.

```html
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="arrival_time" (change)="onSlotChange($event)">
        <option value="" data-date="" data-slot="">Select Arrival Time</option>
         <ng-container *ngIf="!availablePrevSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availablePrevSlotDate}}">
               <option value=null hidden>-- No Slot Available --</option>
            </optgroup>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngIf="availablePrevSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availablePrevSlotDate}}">
               <option value=null hidden>HH:MM</option>
               <option *ngFor="let slot of availablePrevSlots" [value]="slot">{{slotToString(slot)}}</option>
            </optgroup>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngIf="!availableSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availableSlotDate}}">
               <option value=null hidden>-- No Slot Available --</option>
            </optgroup>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngIf="availableSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availableSlotDate}}">
               <option value=null hidden>HH:MM</option>
               <option *ngFor="let slot of availableSlots" [value]="slot">{{slotToString(slot)}}</option>
            </optgroup>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngIf="!availableNextSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availableNextSlotDate}}">
               <option value=null hidden>-- No Slot Available --</option>
            </optgroup>
         </ng-container>
         <ng-container *ngIf="availableNextSlots">
            <optgroup label="{{availableNextSlotDate}}">
                <option value=null hidden>HH:MM</option>
                <option *ngFor="let slot of availableNextSlots" [value]="slot">{{slotToString(slot)}}</option>
            </optgroup>
          </ng-container>
      </select>
```

Now I am getting the selected time/spot value with onchange function but I want to get the option label as well
Is there any method to get the optgroup label ?

also once we submit the form we save the slot in data base and on edit page we show it with data binding but as multiple optgroup can have same slots it always shows first optgroup value selected

no sure how to show exact optgroup value selected here.

Comment: It's a strange pattern to have duplicate value in an option list. I think first of all you should prefix the value of the option like previous-available-1000 / available-1500 etc... optgroup is not meant to handle duplicate select values. Then the @e.m.b should to the work

Comment: @PierreMallet Yeah, it seems its the only way to handle it but it requires a lot of coding as I was using for binding and now have to use function to get and set the values, may b I will use some hidden fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use VanillaJS in order to accomplish that, in your change function write this:

```
const selectedIndex = ev.target.selectedIndex;
const optGroupLabel = ev.target.options[selectedIndex].parentNode.getAttribute('label');
```

And here's a working stackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-64vvdn

Comment: Seems will work to get the label name but how can I show the value selected if there are same values in different opt group

Comment: You can get the selected value from the event parameter, and maybe you want to concatenate the two strings ? Here's an example: `selectedOption = optGroupLabel + ev.target.value;` I also updated the stackblitz

Comment: Although I didnt get the solution for showing option selected if there are duplicate values in 2 optgroup, it worked for me